# MySQL timeout for 1 database, others are OK - MySQL and InnoDB data dictionaries are out of sync

Tags: mysql

I can't connect to MySQL for a specific database, even from phpMyAdmin, i get the following error:

`#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).`

In MySQL logs I see:

`130404 1:18:09 InnoDB: MySQL and InnoDB data dictionaries are out of sync.
InnoDB: Unable to find the AUTOINC column id in the InnoDB table strangedb/table.
InnoDB: We set the next AUTOINC column value to 0,
InnoDB: in effect disabling the AUTOINC next value generation.
InnoDB: You can either set the next AUTOINC value explicitly using ALTER TABLE
InnoDB: or fix the data dictionary by recreating the table.
130404 1:25:13 InnoDB: MySQL and InnoDB data dictionaries are out of sync.
InnoDB: Unable to find the AUTOINC column id in the InnoDB table strangedb/table.
InnoDB: We set the next AUTOINC column value to 0,
InnoDB: in effect disabling the AUTOINC next value generation.
InnoDB: You can either set the next AUTOINC value explicitly using ALTER TABLE
InnoDB: or fix the data dictionary by recreating the table.
130404 1:25:13 InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139934538761984 in file handler/ha_innodb.cc line 8290
InnoDB: Failing assertion: auto_inc > 0
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.`

I can confirm MySQL is working OK for all other tables.

I have gone through the link about forcing recovery but I am not an MySQL ninja, I can `select * from strangedb.table;` OK and the content is listed, what would be the next steps to dump the data and reimport to a new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be corruption like the error mentioned. I was able to view the contents of the table via the MySQL utility and did the following:

1. Created a new table from the existing schema of the corrupt table
2. Copy data from old to new

Commands below:

```
USE strangedb;
CREATE TABLE table_new LIKE table;
INSERT table_new SELECT * FROM table;
```

Once copied across safely, I could drop the old table `DROP TABLE table;` and rename the lifeboat table `RENAME TABLE table_new TO table;`

In my case it was OK as I didn't have any association constraints, I would imagine for more complex scenarios those would need to be recreated.